# What this TypeScript type annotation actually means?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use this line of code but looks like its using typescript. My project is not. I need to make it work in ReactJS (newbie to JS and ReactJS). Just need to understand what this below means and how to make it reactjs compliant.

```
const VideoPreview = ({ stream }: { stream: MediaStream | null }) => {
```

Changing to this fixes it, but do NOT know what `| null` means?

```
const VideoPreview = ({ stream }) => {
```

Comment: `| null` is the return type...

Comment: It means the `stream` argument is a `MediaStream` or it's `null`.

Comment: The title and the body of the question seem to ask two different things. The title appears to ask how to remove type annotations, whereas the body asks what a type annotation means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ stream: MediaStream | null }
```

this line basically means that `stream` can be a type of `MediaStream` or `null` so `||` means it is OR, you can read about it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_operators.htm)